# Restructure bulky class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, refactoring

I have an ActiveRecord model `Reservation`.
It got to the point that the class is to large and does too much.
I would like to split it into a few different ones and place those under the `Reservation` module.

Unfortunately this will break the app.

At this moment I see following options:

- namespace it to something like `ReservationConcerns` or similar
- add the functionality to the `Reservation` class itself, but physically move it to the subdir (`Reservation` would be in `app/models/reservation.rb`, `Reservation::Pipeline` would be in `app/models/reservation/pipeline.rb` etc).

So the question is **how to structure the different concerns** of a feature already having it as one single, bulky class without breaking the app.

Comment: Why specifically does the app break? Is there anything to stop you from changing both the Reservation class and the code that interfaces with it?

Comment: The rest of the app interfaces with the `Reservation`, so I'd like to keep it that to avoid changing existing conventions in the app (thus not to break it). Just restructure the implementation.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to split up a Ruby class into different components without changing its public interface, one solution is to use modules:

```
# app/models/reservation.rb
class Reservation < ActiveRecord::Base
  # associations, validations, etc.

  include Pipeline
end

# app/models/reservation/pipeline.rb
module Reservation::Pipeline
  def some_pipeline_method
    # ...
  end

  def other_pipeline_method
    # ...
  end
end
```

ActiveRecord also provides [observers](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Observer.html), which "is a great way to reduce the clutter that normally comes when the model class is burdened with functionality that doesn't pertain to the core responsibility of the class". Observers often make heavy use of the [ActiveModel::Dirty](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Dirty.html) methods.

These suggestions are complimentary: modules can help you group your interface into more local chunks, while observers can make backend details more self-contained. From here, it's difficult to be more specific without knowing exactly what pieces you have that you're trying to break out.

Comment: You cannot define both module and a class with the same name (which you do here).

Comment: Which module and class have the same name?

Comment: Ahh, I didn't realise, we can define module within a class using full path `Reservation::Pipeline` instead of `class Reservation; module Pipeline...`. Not sure if I need to worry that the module is defined as part of the class.